# Using traceroute in an if statement in a bash script

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address, qnx, traceroute

I'm trying to execute code based on whether or not traceroute gets a response from a specific IP address. So:

```
if traceroute 123.456.78.9
then
   option 1
else
   option 2
```

My issue is that whether I get a response from the IP address or not, option 1 is always executed.

I've tried this using 'ping' instead of traceroute and it works, but I don't have the option of using ping in the final code.

**More Details:**

1. Running on QNX OS
2. Success is constituted by a response from the host and failure is constituted by no response from the host
3. Success output:

   ```
   traceroute to 123.456.78.9 (123.456.78.9), 1 hops max, 40 byte packets
    1  123.456.78.9 (123.456.78.9)  0.000 ms  1.000 ms  0.000 ms
   ```
4. Failure output:

   ```
   traceroute to 123.456.78.90 (123.456.78.90), 1 hops max, 40 byte packets
    1  *
   ```

Comment: Run `traceroute 123.456.78.9`, and then `echo $?` to check the exit status. If it's `0`, that's treated as success. If that's `1`, it's treated as a failure.

Comment: If traceroute always reports success when it exits, even if it wasn't able to reach the remote system, bring that up with your OS vendor -- they're the ones who provided traceroute to you; it's not part of bash. OTOH, if you want to read traceroute's stdout and determine success or failure from there, we can do that, but you'll need to provide *much* more information in your question (specifically, sample output in both success and failure cases, and details on what you expect to constitute a failure). Without those details, answers are liable to work only on the OS run by the answerer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've added more details based on your comment. Also, I'm not really sure how to check the exit status using echo $ as you mentioned above.

Comment: `echo $?`. The `?` is part of it. Compare `true; echo $?` with `false; echo $?`. You'll see that the former is 0 (an exit status which `if` and other conditionals will treat as success), and the latter is 1 (which, like any other nonzero value, is treated as a failure).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that traceroute always echos an output even if there's no valid host, so you need to check for valid responses first

You have to check if valid response is received or not

Try using

```
n=`traceroute 123.456.78.9|grep ms|wc|sed 's/ //g' |cut -d ' ' -f 1`

if [ $n -eq 0 ]                                                         
then
    echo 'failed'
else
    echo 'success'
fi
```

Comment: If `ms` is only found at all in the success case, couldn't it just be `if traceroute 123.456.78.9 | grep -q ' ms'; then echo success; else echo failed; fi`? The pipeline seems like overkill.

Comment: (Also, as http://shellcheck.net/ would note, better to quote expansions, as in `[ "$n" -eq 0 ]`; that way if you somehow ended up with an empty value for `n`, you'll get a more useful error message from `test`).

Comment: Thanks for this refine